# Is there a way to use w3c-validator as a local instance using either a session cookie or using username and password?

Tags: unit-testing, w3c, validation, w3c-validation

I would like to integrate the usage of w3c-validator into unit testing. Is there a way to get around authentication to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C's HTML validator is [open source](http://validator.w3.org/source/) so you can run it locally. Alternatively, I'd recommend [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).